# Can't not assign value to Table Type which is parameterized in stored procedure when it's in large size

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a trouble when pushing over 17000 rows to a Table Type as a parameter in SQL stored procedure, it works well in 500 records:[workwellin500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVvaU.png)

However when the size of the parameter grow up to 17344 lines,  I couldn't catch the execution of the remote call procedure in Profiler SQL Server as I did in the image above. The code doesn't throw any exception and continue to run others.
Here the code C# that invokes the store procedure.

```
private async Task SyncSAPPricesSap(DataTable data)
    {
        using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetValue<string>(SystemConstants.ConnectionStrings));
        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        try
        {
            var sqlComm = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SP_SAPPrices_Sap_Sync]", sqlConnection);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataSync", data);
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlComm.CommandTimeout = 600;
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("SyncSAPPricesSap::" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            throw new DomainException("Async SAPPrices from SAP failure");
        }
    }
```

Comment: as you are having command timeout to 6 minutes, you are getting timed out, for huge number of rows. It is nothing to do with parametrized table valued datatype

Comment: @VenkataramanR if I have connection timeout error, then the pointer execution must jump in catch block  but in my case it's not

Comment: As a general point, please stop using `AddWithValue`. Additionally passing a large amount of data in a `DataTable` could cause problems, because there is no buffering. You might be better off using a `DbReader` (put your `DataTable` into a `DataSet` and then call `CreateDataReader` on the `DataSet`).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Is this just an issue with Profiler showing the TVP data? Importantly, it looks like the DataTable schema (all strings of max length) may not match the TVP type. Specify the proper type of each column in the DataTable along the the actual max length for string columns.